# PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have an array

```
$array = ['download.png', 'download-1.png', 'download-2.png']
```

I want a regular expression that can match all three elements. So far I've tried and gotten something like

```
/('."$filename".')\-*[0-9]*$/
```

where $filename = 'download.png'

If it helps I am trying to use the regex in this

```
foreach($len as $value){        
                    if(preg_match('/('."$filename".')\-*[0-9]*$/', $value->getValue()) ){ 
                    $array[] = $value->getValue();
                    var_dump( $array); echo '<br>';
                    }
                }
```

help me anyone thanks in advance!

Comment: is `filename` always = _download_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution without regex.
Explode on "-" if there is two items in the array it has "-" included in name.

```
$array = ['download.png', 'download-1.png', 'download-2.png'];

Foreach($array as $val){
    $exp = explode("-", $val);
    If(isset($exp[1])){ 
        Echo "name is: " . $exp[0] . "-" . $exp[1] . "\n";
    }Else{
        Echo "name is: " . $exp[0] ."\n";
    }
 }
```

https://3v4l.org/5ElW3

Answer (score 1):

Try [`"/" . explode($filename, '.')[0] . "(?:-\d)?\.png/"`](https://regex101.com/r/Uh4IoK/1)

`explode($filename, '.')[0]` splits `$filename` into `['download', 'png']` and then gets the first element in that array, `download`.

`(?:-\d)?` is an optional (it's the `?` that makes it optional) non-capturing group (that's the `(?:`) that matches a dash and then a number. This means that it's optional to match the `-1`.

From what I understand from your question, `$value->getValue()` is something like `download-2.png`. Your regex isn't matching the `.png` extension. I've added `\.png` to my regex for this.

Comment: `$filename` contains the file extension.

Comment: @somesh If my answer helped you, don't forget to mark as accepted :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers